# Java 7 on OS X showing 'identifier expected' error for multiple catch

Tags: java, ant, osx-mavericks

On my machine for some reason I can't compile a class with a multiple catch.  This should be working in java 7

I am using OS X Mavericks.

`.bash_profile` has export `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)`

from the command line

```
java -version

java version "1.7.0_79"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

However, I am getting this error when using `ant` from the command line

```
&lt;identifier&gt; expected
    [javac]         } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
```

Here is the

```
try {

    super.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("updatePartItems",
               IBasketItem.class).invoke(this, item);

} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {

    log.error("Method updatePartItems is not available on " + this.getClass());

}
```

Here is my path:

```
todd@tpurcell-mac:echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.2.4/ebin:/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.2.4/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.1/bin::/marketlive/tools/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.1/bin:
```

I have tried re-installing the latest 1.7 jdk and can't seem to find a way around this issue.

Comment: What version of Java is ant using? Make sure it's not trying to compile down to an earlier version

Comment: MadProgrammer, how do I check that.  I set java_home in my bash_profile. and I assumed everything would pick up that variable. How do I test if ant is using my java_home?

Comment: Compiler errors are printed, not thrown.

Comment: For testing how something was compiled (that is already byte code): javap -verbose My.class | grep major

Comment: Does your ant file have something like this in it:
<javac target="1.5" .../> If so it's targeting 1.5 compatibility.